# Como persistir e atualizar o Token Access do oauth 2.0 do Google?

Tags: oauth2, token

Tenho uma conta no Google Analytics e preciso do Token Access para fazer algumas requisições que me retornam dados dessa minha conta. Sempre que eu uso o oauth para autenticar dá certo, porém, quando eu troco de página os dados dos meus Tokens somem. Já armazenei eles em uma $_SESSION (php) para passar para outra página, e funciona normalmente, porém depois de 1 hora o Access Token expira e não funciona mais, e também não atualiza automaticamente mesmo com o Refresh Token.
Alguém pode me ajudar? Estou há um bom tempo com esse problema sem conseguir resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o meu problema.
Achei este artigo na internet: https://ctrlq.org/code/20363-google-api-php-oauth2-example
O código apresentado ali faz com que os dados sejam salvos em um arquivo .txt (você pode optar por salvar no banco também) e todos os dados continuam salvos e verificando se o token expirou.